# Cant enter for loop

Tags: java, netbeans

The objective is to create an account registration method for an ATM object. But I keep breaking on the if statement used to enter the loop. I assume my "wording" is off, but I'm drawing a blank on how to fix it. Any suggestions? The problem itself is at `if(acc[i].getAcc()==0)`where `.getAcc` is a getter in a class.

```
package atmassignment;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class AtmAssignment {
static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
static int cou = 1;
static Account[] acc = new Account[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
    }
    public static void menu(){
        char opt;
        System.out.println("Thanks for accessing ATManager.");
        System.out.println("Please select a menu option to proceed.");
        System.out.println("1-Register a new account, 2-Access an account, 0-Exit ATManager");
        opt = in.next().charAt(0);

        switch (opt) {
            case '1':
                newAccount();
                break;

            case '2':
                selAccount();
                break;

            case '0':
                System.out.println("Goodbye.");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry.");             
                break;
        }
    }
    public static void newAccount(){
        System.out.println("Account registration");
      for (int i = 0; i < acc.length; i++){
          if(acc[i].getAcc()==0){
              System.out.println("Please enter your first name...");
              String fn = in.next();
              System.out.println("Please enter your last name...");
              String ln = in.next();
              System.out.println("Please enter your address...");
              String ad = in.next();
              System.out.println("Please provide a contact number...");
              String cn = in.next();
              Customer cus = new Customer(fn, ln,ad,cn);
              System.out.println("What is your starting balance...");
              double bal = in.nextDouble();
              acc[i] = new Account(cou, bal, cus);
              System.out.println("Your account is registered as ID#"+cou);
              break;           
          } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, no more accounts can be created.");
                break;
            }
      }
    }



}
```

Comment: As samgak suggested check if the int value being returned by the method getAcc is even being intialized!

Answer (score 1):

This allocates an array of object references:

```
static Account[] acc = new Account[10];
```

However it doesn't actually allocate any objects, so you are probably getting a null pointer exception when you try to access the first element. In your init code, do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    acc[i] = new Account();
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `acc[i].getAcc()==0` before actually constructing your objects. Maybe modify the for loop so that you create your objects and then gather input and update your objects later on with setter methods? This of course requires that you have some sort of default constructor for your Account class.

```
acc[j through maxLength] = new Account(); //where j spans the entire length of the array
for (int i = 0; i < acc.length; i++){
          if(acc[i].getAcc()==0){
              System.out.println("Please enter your first name...");
              String fn = in.next();
              System.out.println("Please enter your last name...");
              String ln = in.next();
              System.out.println("Please enter your address...");
              String ad = in.next();
              System.out.println("Please provide a contact number...");
              String cn = in.next();
              Customer cus = new Customer(fn, ln,ad,cn);
              System.out.println("What is your starting balance...");
              double bal = in.nextDouble();
              acc[i].setContact(###);
              acc[i].setBalance(###); //ETC
              System.out.println("Your account is registered as ID#"+cou);
              break;           
          } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, no more accounts can be created.");
                break;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't populate your Account[] array. Here I only can see you declare your array like -

```
static Account[] acc = new Account[10];
```

So after that when you are trying to get you array element using for loop than you can't access them. You are getting the error at  `if(acc[i].getAcc()==0)` this line. So I suggest remove the if check since you are populating your Account later in this line - `acc[i] = new Account(cou, bal, cus);`

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.